# MySQL: How do I group a SELECT statement output combining : "Technology 01" and "Tech 01"

Tags: mysql

lets say I have entries in a MySQL database:

- "Technology 01"
- "tech 01"
- "Tech 1"
- "Tech 02"
- "Tech 2"
- "Technology 03"

How do I form an SQL statement that groups them together to output something like:

- Tech 1, 3
- Tech 2, 2
- Tech 3, 1

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: what's your logic to get data in this form

Comment: The entries in the MySQL database were extracted from a 500+/- user google spreadsheet